# Sorting data by column in java

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

So I have all this data that I'm eventually feeding into an object that is to be displayed into a JTable. What I need to do is sort all of the data by the Averages and feed them into the Object for the JTable in a sorted fashion that shows the data from High to low by average.

This is all of my data

```
private String[] Names = new String[10];
private char[] Sex = new char[10];
private int[][] Score = new int[10][5];
private double[] Averages = new double[10];
private char[] LetterGrades = new char[10];
```

This is how I feed it in unsorted

```
Object[][] data = new Object[10][9];
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      data[i][0] = Names[i];
      data[i][1] = Sex[i];
      data[i][2] = Score[i][0];
      data[i][3] = Score[i][1];
      data[i][4] = Score[i][2];
      data[i][5] = Score[i][3];
      data[i][6] = Score[i][4]
      data[i][7] = Averages[i];
      data[i][8] = LetterGrades[i];
    }
```

I've been thinking of doing it with an ArrayList but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to feed it into an array list than sort it by the Average column. I'm not really sure if I can sort an object. Any insight or a point in the right direction would be awesome.

Comment: You really should be using a custom object rather than a multidimensional array, and sorting objects is easy with a `Comparator`.

Comment: @chrylis thanks for the advice. I'll do that.

Comment: unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`JTable` has sorting capabilities built in.

You can activate it by calling `table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);`

See [Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) for more details

Comment: Yeah, you should have seen the loops we used have to jump through before this was implemented :P